# Checking my understanding: $\gamma$ Gaussian on $X$ implies that $X^\ast \subset L^2(\gamma)$?

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a locally convex space, and let $\mathcal{E}(X)$ denote the cylindrical $\sigma$-field. Bogachev defines a measure $\mu$ on $(X, \mathcal{E}(X))$ to be Gaussian if the pushforward, $\mu \circ f^{-1}$ for any $f \in X^\ast$ is Gaussian.

He then claims: if $\mu$ is Gaussian, then by definition $X^\ast \subset L^2(\mu)$.

I want to make sure I am understanding why this is the case.

Here is my reasoning: say $f \in X^\ast$ and $\mu$ on $(X, \mathcal{E}(X))$ is Gaussian. Then $\mu \circ f^{-1}$ is Gaussian, with mean $a_\mu(f)$ and variance $\sigma^2(f)$. Then
$$
\int f^2(x) \, \mu(dx) = \int t^2 \, [\mu \circ f^{-1}](dt) 
$$
Writing $t^2 = (t - a_\mu(f))^2 +2(t-a_\mu(f))a_\mu(f) + (a_\mu(f))^2$,
we find that
$$
\|f\|_{L^2(\mu)}^2 = \sigma^2(f) + (a_\mu(f))^2 < \infty. 
$$
Hence $f \in L^2(\mu)$.

The basic idea seems to be that $f \in X^\ast$ implies that the projection
$\mu \circ f^{-1}$ is Gaussian, in particular that it has finite variance, which is
essentially the same as the $L^2$-norm of $f$ under the original measure.

(The secondary manipulation is the standard formula $E[(X- E X)^2] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$, just re-arranged, but I wanted to just write down the full details to keep it complete.)

Comment: Gaussian random variables have finite moments of all orders.  I don't think you have to write all those inequalities.

Comment: I see, but the idea is simply that if $f \in X^\ast$ then $\gamma \circ f^{-1}$ is a random variable with all moments (including second), so that $f \in X^\ast$. Am I correct then that $X^\ast \subset L^p$ for all $p$? Even for $p > 2$?

Comment: Yes, $X^{*}\subset L^{p}$ for all $p>0$.